# Partial derivatives (calculus)

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I am new to calculus and am somewhat confused by the details of partial derivatives in more complex constructions. I was asked to work out the following and was wondering if anybody could give me some feedback. Many thanks in advance!

> The function $Z(x,y)$ is defined by the formula $$yz + \sin(z) + xyz - y\cos (z) = -1$$ around point $(1,1,0)$. Calculate $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}(1,1)$.

Here is what I've tried:

$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y} = z + yz_{y} + \cos(z)·z_{y}+x·z_{y} - \cos(z)+y·\sin(z)·z_{y}=0$$

$$z_{y}(y+\cos(z)+x+y·\sin(z)) = -z+\cos(z)$$

$$z_{y} = \frac{-z + \cos(z)}{y + \cos(z)+ x +y·\sin(z)}$$

By putting in $(1,1,0)$, I then get to $$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}(1,1)=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: You shouldn't have that first $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}$, just start by taking the derivatives with respect to $y$ like you did.  Also, you  are missing several product rule steps on the $xyz$ term.

Comment: @DMcMor
thank you! I have had a second look at the $xyz$ term: should its derivative come out as $xz + xyz_y$? I am doing my best to be consistent, but it is pretty confusing...

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$yz+\sin(z)+xyz-y\cos(z)=-1$$

Taking partial derivative with respect to $y$,
$$ z + yz_{y} + \cos(z)z_{y}+x z +xyz_y - \cos(z)+y·\sin(z)·z_{y}=0$$

Now, substitute $(1,1,0)$,

$$0+z_y+\cos (0)z_y+0+(1)(1)z_y-\cos(0)+\sin(0)z_y=0$$

$$3z_y-1=0$$

$$z_y=\frac13$$